# How do I make my form work. I designed it using bootstrap. I don't know php.

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

I designed a contact form using html bootstrap, but I don't know how to make it work. I have the following code. I saw few tutorials online that used php to get the contact form work, but I don't have any knowledge of php. Can anyone help me with this.  I would be grateful if someone can help me to get my form work. The following is what I have so far

```
<form method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>

    <div class="controls">

        <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="name">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>

    <div class="controls">

        <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="website">Website</label>

    <div class="controls">

        <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="website">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>

    <div class="controls">

        <textarea class="input-medium" id="comment" rows="5"></textarea>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-actions">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>

    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="#">

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to code the server side page of your contact form for you? If so, why don't you take one of the free PHP script that you can find on the web?

Comment: I agree to @AurelioDeRosa. I also recommend you to learn some basics of PHP. Every web designer knows how to code up the server-side part of his/her contact form at least.

Comment: Nobody can do this for you. Look into GET and POST requests with PHP. After that try to figure out AJAX so that your form will respond the way people expect it too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the page below and name it as contact.php. Create another html called "thanks.html". It will shown after user submit the form

```
<?php
    $from ="xyz@gmail.com";
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
        $name = (isset($_POST['name'])) : trim($_POST['name']) : "";
        $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) : trim($_POST['email']) : "";
        $website = (isset($_POST['website'])) : trim($_POST['website']) : "";
        $comment = (isset($_POST['comment'])) : trim($_POST['comment']) : "";

        if(!empty($email)){
            $subject = "new mail";
            $content ="A user has send email<br />
            name: $name<br />
            email: $email<br />
            website: $website<br />
            comment: $comment<br />";

            $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
            mail($email, $subject, $content, $headers); 
            header("location:thanks.html");

        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="website">Website</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="website" name="website">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea class="input-medium" id="comment" name="comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you follow following Steps :

1.Create a table in database ex.`Data`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_data` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

2. now Modify your HTML code as follow assign Names to each input fields:

```
 <form method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal">

     <div class="control-group">

       <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>

       <div class="controls">

         <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="name" name="name">

       </div>

     </div>

     <div class="control-group">

       <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>

       <div class="controls">

         <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email" name="email">

       </div>

     </div>

     <div class="control-group">

       <label class="control-label" for="website">Website</label>

       <div class="controls">

         <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="website" name="website">

       </div>

     </div>

     <div class="control-group">

       <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>

       <div class="controls">

         <textarea class="input-medium" id="comment" rows="5" name="comment"></textarea>

       </div>

     </div>

     <div class="form-actions">

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>

       <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
       <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="http://www.sarahmustafa.com/contact.html">
    </div>
 </form>
```

3.Now Change You contact-form-submission.php as follows and change ttable name in that if you want :

```
$dbhost='localhost';//you can change to your host (www.google/fff/fff')
$dbuser='root';//you can change to your Username of DB (ex. root)
$dbpass='';//you can change to your Password (ex. '')
$dbname='Data';//you can change to your Database created on DB   (ex.user_data)


db_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$website=$_POST["website"];
$comment=$_POST["comment"];
//change the field to actual Databse fields 
$sql="INSERT INTO `user_data` (`name`,`email`,`comment`,`website`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$comment','$website')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);



function db_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)
{
    $conn = mysql_pconnect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    if (!$conn)
        return "connect_failed";

    if (!mysql_select_db($dbname))
        return "db_select_failed";
    return "succes";
}
```

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO NO NO

Do NOT blindly put user-generated data into your SQL query. Use prepared statements instead. You're only opening up to SQL Injection with this code.

Comment: @codran +1. This has been also discussed a LOT of time on this website.